# Android Java IF THEN ELSE.... =/

Tags: android

I'm attempting to use IF THEN to add to and from integers in code:

```
 one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            subtotal = 1;
            if (variable1==1) (counter + 1)

            else if (variable1==2) then (counter + 1);
            display.setText("Your total is" + counter);
        }
    });
```

But i get errors in my formatting i think.. =/

Many Thanks!

Comment: and what errors, specifically, do you get?

Comment: You should have a read on [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Comment: (#1) The method then(String) in the type calculatorActivity is not applicable for the arguments (int) (#2) Multiple markers at this line
 - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
 - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete 
  Expression

Comment: you can refer this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513218/android-java-how-to-use-if-then-else/42300042#42300042

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use curly brackets `{}`.
Also, saying `counter + 1` doesn't make much sense. I'm sure you mean `counter += 1`, which can be written as `counter++`, because you're only adding one.

```
if (variable1==1) {
    counter++;
} else if (variable1==2) {
    counter++;
}
```

Also, since the body of the `if`s are the same, you can have both expressions in the same `if`.

```
if (variable1==1 || variable1==2) {
    counter++;
}
```