# Android java: how to use if-then-else

Tags: java, android, eclipse, if-statement

i'm using eclipse with ADT plugin, and i'm developing an app where i want to use if then and else.
i want to do this

```
if file.txt not exist
then do    
startDownload();
readFile();
else  delete file.txt
```

Comment: You would want to first read up basics of the Java programming language?

Comment: i don't know to write doesn't exist

Comment: that's not java syntax.

Comment: this is exist, how can i put don'texist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code to try:

```
File f = new File(filePathString);
if(!f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
 startDownload();
 readFile();
} 
else { 
   try { 
      file.delete();
   } catch (Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below expressions for "**if-then-else**" condition in android,

```
boolean isValid = true;
(isValid?"your_if_value_whatever":"your_else_value");
```